# подключение к вайфай из командной строки

Tags: linux, debian, консоль, wifi

случайно поставил дебиан без графического окружения, не хотелось бы переустанавливать систему целиком поэтому нужно установить соединение по вайфай что бы доставить необходимое GUI, но вот с этим проблема терминал не реагирует даже на iwconfig  пишет команд нот фонд

Comment: А на `nmtui` он как реагирует? Это, конечно, если у вас стоит network manager.

Comment: Посмотрите это: [ссылка](http://blog.sedicomm.com/2018/05/07/kak-podklyuchit-wi-fi-ispolzuya-terminal-linux-s-pomoshhyu-komandy-nmcli/)

Comment: не реагирует по ходу дела встала минимальная система

Comment: В современных системах команда `iw`. Но даже если её нет, пакеты можно протащить через USB с другого компьютера. Но вообще это весёлое занятие. Вначале доступ к сети, потом аутентификатор (обычно `wpa-supplicant`), потом ...